"Document Object Model" smart screenshots in non-Firefox browsers
Firefox has smart screenshots based on using the Document Object Model (DOM) of a webpage -- it autosuggests features of the webpage to screenshot as you move the mouse.
Do any other browsers have this feature?
I've searched Chrome, Edge, and Brave for this functionality or related addons, but see nothing.

If you are simply looking for snipping tools on these browsers, they actually have that
Microsoft Edge
Right Click on the page --> Screenshot (or Ctrl+Shift+S)
Chrome
Enable Desktop Screenshots flag at chrome://flags/#sharing-desktop-screenshots. After relaunch, go to Ellipsis menu on the top right --> Save and share --> Screenshot
If you mean the feature of "autosuggesting features of the webpage to screenshot as you move the mouse", they don't have that. Consider sending feedback to the Dev Team respectively.
